# when doing OOP cannot output a String in if else

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

when i was doing a *if else* statement on the get methods
I cannot output a check `String` in `int` `length` and want to set Gh to `"AAAAA"`
the code is

```
public String getGh(){
        int length = Gh.length();
        if (length == 0){
            Gh="AAAAA";
        }else{
            Gh= null;
        }
    return this.Gh;
}
public String ShowGh() {
    return ("Title: "+this.Gh);
```

output is nothink, please help

Comment: side note: `int length = Gh.length();` is *dangerous* it throws exception on `Gh == null`

Comment: so , what should i do?

Comment: java  language with OOP

Comment: A pretty weird question. What happens if you do this 'ShowGh(); ShowGh();`? Try that, it is fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember that `String` can well be `null` and thus

```
int length = Gh.length();
```

will *throw exception*. That's why you have to check for `null` manually `null == Gh` before doing `Gh.length`. I suggest something like this:

```
private String Gh = ""; // no null but empty string by default

...

public String getGh {
  // If Gh is null or empty, assign "AAAAA"; empty otherwise
  Gh = (null == Gh || 0 == Gh.length()) 
    ? "AAAAA"
    : "";

  return Gh;
}

//TODO: Turn ShowGh() into camel case: showGh()
public String ShowGh() {
    //DONE: you probably mean "getGh()" instead of Gh
    // return ("Title: " + Gh);
    // getGh() tries to get Gh, change its value to "AAAAA" and we have "Title: AAAAA"
    return "Title: " + getGh();
}
```

**Edit**: if you want to get rid of side effects within `getGh()` and implement the logic in a typical manner:

```
public String getGh {
  // Just return Gh value
  return Gh;
}

public String setGh(String value) {
  // If Gh is null or empty, assign "AAAAA"; empty otherwise
  Gh = (null == value || 0 == value.length()) 
    ? "AAAAA
    : value;
}
```

Comment: i still have error on your code error: cannot find symbol
 symbol:   variable length
  location: variable Gh of type String

Comment: @Kaki Lam: Sorry for typo, it should be `length()` in case of `String` and `length` in case of array

Comment: i change that it work but still no output on the text java ,why?

Comment: @Kaki Lam: you, probably want `return "Title: " + getGh();` instead of `return ("Title: " + Gh);`

Comment: sorry i think using null is do no change the test input ,am i wrong? 
i just want to change the String test input when it is ""

Comment: @Kaki Lam: if you don't want to work with `null`, assign empty string to the field `private String Gh = "";` and do npt assign `null` to the value: `: "";` instead of `: null;`

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me.I mean the case is when i input something ,it will show the same input
but when the input is nothing , It will show AAAAA and i using length to check

Comment: @Kaki Lam: yes, it's the side effect implemented in `getGh()`. Do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: but is it must using set get methods by get() and set()?if it can get rid of it ,can you show me how to do it?or is any simple way to do checking and output